# Possible to submit app from 10.10 beta to Mac AppStore?

Tags: macos, appstore-approval, mac-app-store

While using the Mavericks Beta I was unpleasantly surprised and caught off guard by the fact that I could not submit my applications / updates to the store anymore.

I had to install all my certificates on another Macintosh which was not running the beta OS.

Did this change with 10.10? Can I install it and still upload updates and new applications to the (Mac) AppStore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer NO because I now have the same problem trying to submit an app built using 10.10 Yosemite. I really don't want to revert my system to Mavericks. Yosemite is a very nice upgrade - people are going to like it!

I have only a minor issue upgrading to Xcode6-Beta and it has an improved UI for submitting to the App Store so I hope that the Store will allow it to be used sometime soon. Does anyone know the time frame? The minor issue is that NSPathControl has been deprecated and XIBs having an NSPathControl can cause an immediate Xcode crash trying to display the NSPathControl.

Comment: take a look at my answer for the time frame.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't you can start submitting your apps/updates when OS X Yosemite is released to the public sometime in the fall. 
Source: Apple